# Fixed effects regression in R: difference in specification

Tags: r, regression, lm

I'm doing a few regressions using state and year fixed effects. There are two ways that I've done it:

```
reg1 <- lm(x ~ y + z + factor(year) + factor(state) + year:state, data=df)
```

and:

```
reg1 <- lm(x ~ y + z + factor(year) + factor(state) + factor(year)*factor(state), data=df)
```

but I can't explain the difference in results between using each way.

Does anyone know the difference between `year:state` and `factor(year)*factor(state)` when using the `lm` function?

I know that `plm` does that for you, but in that specific case, I have to add the fixed effects manually.

Comment: data set name and location?

Comment: The data set is a state-year panel, I named it `df` for this generic example.

Comment: Actually, there are two differences here: 1) `:` vs. `*` (see `?formula` for that), 2) using the plain variables vs. using the variables turned into a factor.